# In Python, how do I select the columns of a dataframe satisfying a condition on the number of NaN?

Tags: python, apply, nan

I hope someone could help me. I'm new to Python, and I have a dataframe with 111 columns and over 40 000 rows. All the columns contain NaN values (some columns contain more NaN's than others), so I want to drop those columns having at least 80% of NaN values. How can I do this?

To solve my problem, I tried the following code

```
df1=df.apply(lambda x : x.isnull().sum()/len(x) < 0.8, axis=0)
```

The function `x.isnull().sum()/len(x)` is to divide the number of NaN in the column x by the length of x, and the part < 0.8 is to choose those columns containing less than 80% of NaN.

The problem is that when I run this code I only get the names of the columns together with the boolean "True" but I want the entire columns, not just the names. What should I do?

Comment: when you have the names of the columns you want to drop, you can use the pandas drop function on your original dataframe :http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html You need to specify axis=1 to drop columns

Comment: You mean something like df=df.drop(df1, axis=1) ? Still doesn't work, my dataframe remains the same.

Comment: no i mean something like df.drop(cols, axis=1, inplace=True). No assignment, due to inplace, cols are the column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
filt = df.isnull().sum()/len(df) < 0.8
df1 = df.loc[:, filt]
```

Comment: Oh you bet me... I'll leave my answer nonetheless, as it has some more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You want to achieve two things. First, you have to find the indices of all columns which contain at most 80% `NaN`s. Second, you want to discard them from your `DataFrame`.

To get a `pandas` `Series` indicating whether a row should be discarded by doing, you can do:

```
df1 = df.isnull().sum(axis=0) < 0.8*df.shape[1]
```

(Btw. you have a typo in your question. You should drop the `==True` as it always tests whether `0.5==True`)

This will give `True` for all column indices to keep, as `.isnull()` gives `True` (or 1) if it is `NaN` and `False` (or 0) for a valid number for every element. Then the `.sum(axis=0)` sums along the columns giving the number of `NaN`s in each column. The comparison is then, if that number is bigger than 80% of the number of columns.

For the second task, you can use this to index your columns by using:

```
df = df[df.columns[df1]]
```

or as suggested in the comments by doing:

```
df.drop(df.columns[df1==False], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I chose the other one because it's short and works perfect. I'd like to upvote your answer but I can't :( , but thanks for writing it anyway!

Comment: @user322778 No problem. It does more or less as the same as theaccepted answer anyway. I just finished it before I saw that someone else answered and will just leave it here, as it has some additional explanations.